# Get the latest version of project from TFS using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell-2.0, msdeploy, powershell-3.0

I want to write powershell script to get the latest version of project using powershell.

I have the function and code with me . But I am not able to figure it out what are the steps the run the script.

Here is the code:

```
function Get-LatestVersion() { 
$location = get-location 
tf.exe get $location / version:T / recursive / force
```

}

. TFSExtensions.ps1

Please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the PowerShell console or ISE and have changed your directory to the location you want to sync...
You need to "dot source" the file that contains your function (or add it to your profile) so the function is defined in your environment.  It appears like TFSExtensions.ps1 is the name you or someone gave it.  You type a period followed by a space followed by the path to the file and filename (i.e. . ....\MyTools\TFSExtensions.ps1).

Once the function is defined, you can run it by typing its name (and any parameters, if any) which in this case is just Get-LatestVersion.
This function takes the directory that you are working in as the workspace location.  BTW:The forward slashes (/) in the tf.exe command line look like they are not needed.  I was able to run the command without them.
Steve

Comment: What function are you referring to?  "Get-LatestVersion" is the function name you have in your question.  For that, you just need it defined (which is where the "dot source" comment comes from in my answer assuming the function is in a file called TFSExtensions.ps1) and type the function's name.  What is the error you are getting?